# Есть ли встроенный инструмент перемножения двух серий в Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Хочу на выходе увидеть DF из 6 строк и 2ух колонок (т.к. 2**3 = 6). Но получается только 3:

```
import pandas as pd
def get_series(name_column: str, size:int=2):
    return pd.Series([i for i in range(size)], name=name_column)


def get_df():
    return pd.concat([get_series('col1'), get_series('col2', 3)], axis=1)
print(get_df())
```

Итог:

```
   col1  col2
0   0.0     0
1   1.0     1
2   NaN     2
```

Можно, конечно это через инструменты питона реализовать через двойной for, но хотелось бы узнать можно ли это через Pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В `Pandas` есть аналоги любых `SQL JOIN`, в частности есть *декартово произведение* `CROSS JOIN`:

```py
pd.merge(get_series('col1'), get_series('col2', 3), how='cross')
```

На выходе:

```
  col1 col2
0    0    0
1    0    1
2    0    2
3    1    0
4    1    1
5    1    2
```